# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds with readfile create object Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, readfile

I have been practising an exercise for open uni which requires me to create several objects from information retrieved from a text file ..it's almost working but I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException : 1   at line 58. Probably a simple issue but as I am a newbie at this it has me stumped I am sure that I am in bounds with my tokens[] numbering 0 - 8 so I am not sure what is going wrong...any help would be awesome

```
package ReadWriteObjectThang;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NinjaListMain {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileReadWrite jin = new FileReadWrite();
    Scanner scanny = new Scanner(System.in);

    Ninja ninja[] = new Ninja[3];

    System.out.println("Enter 1 to create 3 new Ninja Objects \n Enter 2 to create 3 Ninja Objects from file");
    int choice = scanny.nextInt();
    scanny.nextLine();
    int hp = 0;
    int x = 1;
    int z = 0;
    String info = " ";

    if(choice==1){
        System.out.println("Enter a name for your ninja crew");
        String newCrew = scanny.nextLine();

        for(z = 0;z<3;z++){
            System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
            String name = scanny.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter a weapon: ");
            String weapon = scanny.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter hitpoints in whole numbers: ");
            hp = scanny.nextInt();
            scanny.nextLine();

            ninja[z] = new Ninja(name,weapon,hp);
            info = info + name + " " + weapon + " " + hp + ",";
        }

        jin.write(newCrew, info);

    }
    else if(choice==2){
        System.out.println("Enter file name for ninjas to create");
        String oldCrew = scanny.nextLine();

        String oldInfo = jin.read(oldCrew);
        String tokens[] = oldInfo.split("\\s");
        int w = 0;
        for(z = 0;z < 3;z++){
            if(z==0)
                w = 0;
            else if(z==1)
                w = 3;
            else
                w = 6;

            String name = tokens[0 + w];
            String weapon = tokens[1 + w];     //AIOOBE happens here or line below
            hp = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2 + w]);

            ninja[z] = new Ninja(name,weapon,hp);

        }
    }

    for(int g = 0;g<3;g++){
        System.out.println(ninja[g].getName() + " " + ninja[g].getWeapon() + " " + ninja[g].getHP());
    }

}


}



public class Ninja {


private String name;
private String weapon;
private int hitpoints;


public Ninja(String a, String b, int c){
    name = a;
    weapon = b;
    hitpoints = c;
}
```

Comment: try printing the value of `1+w` and `tokens.length()`, as `1+w may be > tokens.length()`

Comment: can you show the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

The command `oldInfo.split("\\s");` is not returning an array of length 5 or more as you are expecting.

Comment: thanks would it be better to use the tokenizer to split the file instead ..I have an assignment coming up that will require me to split larger amounts of info into an array of objects

Comment: turned out the problem was in my readFile method fixed it and..it works fine now ..the read file produced a string with no spaces ...duh

Answer (score 0):

Your `String tokens[] = oldInfo.split("\\s");` is not large enough for the index you are using...or the index is too large for it. I recommend you do some debugging or simply display some information instead of just thinking to find the bug. The code is obviously not doing what you expect it to do.

You should also not reuse that z variable, declare it in the for loop:
`for (int z = 0; ...`

Comment: Do not forget to up (arrow) the answers if you like them.